# Change DLL File Version (ASP.NET 2005)

Tags: asp.net

I'm working in ASP.NET 2005. After publishing my web site getting all dlls in bin folder with file version 0.0.0.0

How can I change the file version?

Answer (score 2):

If you right click on the project in Visual Studio then click on Assembly information under the Application tab you should see a dialog that allows you to set the version.

here's a screenshot:
http://imagebin.antiyes.com/560